# Case insensitive comparison NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Can anyone point me to any resources about case insensitive comparison in Objective C? It doesn't seem to have an equivalent method to `str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)`

Answer (score 575, accepted):

```
if( [@"Some String" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"some string"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
  // strings are equal except for possibly case
}
```

The documentation is located at [Search and Comparison Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in case when `@"Some String"` is received from any other call and happens to be `nil`, your `if` will give `true` as sending `caseInsensitiveCompare` to `nil` is valid and results in another `nil` which, in our case, compared with `NSOrderedSame` will return `true` (`NSOrderedSame` is defined as 0). This can be a source of quite devastating bugs, as it was in my case. Cheers!

Comment: My workaround for this is to implement that comparison as a method inside a category on `NSString` that returns a boolean. Then if the receiving string is `nil`, the method as a whole returns `NO`.

Answer (score 54):

```
 NSString *stringA;
 NSString *stringB;

 if (stringA && [stringA caseInsensitiveCompare:stringB] == NSOrderedSame) {
     // match
 }
```

**Note:** `stringA &&` is required because when `stringA` is `nil`:

```
 stringA = nil;
 [stringA caseInsensitiveCompare:stringB] // return 0
```

and so happens `NSOrderedSame` is also defined as `0`.

The following example is a typical pitfall:

```
 NSString *rank = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Rank"];
 if ([rank caseInsensitiveCompare:@"MANAGER"] == NSOrderedSame) {
     // what happens if "Rank" is not found in standardUserDefaults
 }
```

Answer (score 46):

An alternative if you want more control than just case insensitivity is:

```
[someString compare:otherString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Numeric search and diacritical insensitivity are two handy options.

Comment: As noted above by matm, this will return true if someString is nil.

Comment: @nh32rg Could'y you just make up for the false positive, by changing the if-statement to something like ```if ([someString compare:otherString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] && someString.length > 0 && someString != (id)[NSNull null])```

Comment: actually, you need to write [...comapre:...] == 0, because compare return NSOrderSame (=0) if two strings are same. for, someString != (id)[NSNull null], I don't think it required, because if null, then, length is zero. I usually compare like this:

if (someString.length > 0 && [someString compare:ortherString options:NSCaseIntensitiveSearch] == 0)

Answer (score 23):

You could always ensure they're in the same case before the comparison:

```
if ([[stringX uppercaseString] isEqualToString:[stringY uppercaseString]]) {
    // They're equal
}
```

The main benefit being you avoid the potential issue described by matm regarding comparing nil strings. You could either check the string isn't nil before doing one of the `compare:options:` methods, or you could be lazy (like me) and ignore the added cost of creating a new string for each comparison (which is minimal if you're only doing one or two comparisons).

Comment: Manipulating the casing for comparing is usually not a wise thing to do (e.g, the turkey test: http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html). When you have language-supported case comparison (such as `caseInsensitiveCompare`), always use that.

Answer (score 8):

A new way to do this. iOS 8

```
let string: NSString = "Café"
let substring: NSString = "É"

string.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(substring) // true
```

Comment: objC version: if( string && [string localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:substring] )

Comment: The OP asks for **"Case insensitive comparison"**. If your solution returns `true` for "Café" and "É", this is definitely is **NOT** a correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (NSComparisonResult)caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)aString
```

Comment: It's much more useful to people if answers have some context and description.

Answer (score 6):

Try this method

```
- (NSComparisonResult)caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)aString
```

Answer (score 6):

Converting Jason Coco's answer to **Swift** for the profoundly lazy :)

```
if ("Some String" .caseInsensitiveCompare("some string") == .OrderedSame)
{
  // Strings are equal.
}
```

Comment: its needed for those whose XCodes refuse to autocomplete! :D

Answer (score 5):

to check with the prefix as in the iPhone ContactApp

```
([string rangeOfString:prefixString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == 0)
```

[this](http://www.themusingsofalostprogrammer.com/2012/04/nsstring-startswithnsstringprefix.html) blog was useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution for swift:

**To make both UpperCase:**

e.g:

```
if ("ABcd".uppercased() == "abcD".uppercased()){
}
```

**or to make both LowerCase:**

e.g:

```
if ("ABcd".lowercased() == "abcD".lowercased()){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On macOS you can simply use `-[NSString isCaseInsensitiveLike:]`, which returns `BOOL` just like `-isEqual:`.

```
if ([@"Test" isCaseInsensitiveLike: @"test"])
    // Success
```

Answer (score -3):

```
NSMutableArray *arrSearchData;  
NSArray *data=[arrNearByData objectAtIndex:i];
NSString *strValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data valueForKey:@"restName"]];
NSRange r = [strValue rangeOfString:key options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if(r.location != NSNotFound)
{
     [arrSearchData addObject:data];
}
```