# Check the file is available based on file name with filemanager in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsfilemanager

How to check file without any case sensitivity is available or not in the current fileManager path directory? 
In current code lower case or higher case for file name string is important.

```
    - (BOOL) findFile{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager new];
    NSArray * subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *myfilePath=nil;
    if([subpaths count]!=0)
        myfilePath=[subpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    if([myfilePath isEqualToString:@"FileName.png"] && myfilePath!=nil){
        myfilePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0],myfilePath];
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Putting both at uppercase could do the trick. `if ([[myfilePath upperCase] isEqualToString:[@"FileName.png" upperCase]])`?, or instead of `isEqualToString:`, you could use `caseInsensitiveCompare:`

Comment: Good. I am going to use caseInsensitiveCompare. Useful answer. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive comparison NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582306/case-insensitive-comparison-nsstring)